# Interactive Grid (IG) ORA-01403 Error in Oracle APEX 5.1.2

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

How can I overcome this {Ajax call returned server error ORA-01403: no data found for} problem? Problem arises ,**When I want to set Order_Status_Field value 2 in IG where query was Order_Status_Id=1.**

My IG query was :

```
SELECT P.ORDER_ID, P.ORDER_STATUS_ID FROM ORDER_DETAILS P WHERE P.ORDER_STATUS_ID=1;
```

My Workspace Name: ZISHAN

User: ZISHANIIUC@GMAIL.COM

Pass: 123

Problem Page No: 3 (Order Report)

**1. Before Updating Order Status:**
[image]

**2. After Updating Order Status:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I saw your are using standard "Interactive Grid - Automatic Row Processing (DML)" process, which is an AJAX approach. this apex behaviour is a call ajax using json format for data. so you have a filter on your sql query

```
SELECT T.ORDER_ID,
       T.TABLE_ID,
       T.TAKEN_BY,
       T.ORDER_STATUS_ID,
       T.TOTAL_COST
FROM ORDER_DETAILS T
 WHERE T.ORDER_STATUS_ID=2
```

and you want to update your filter column (data has change) it's seem like apex do not find the prevouis data filter and return no_data_found (not really sure what happen ) but for solution : .

1. put your filter in interactive grid --> action button ---> filter 
   or
2. write your own custom process

Comment: You are right - after processing the changes APEX tries to requery that row (presumably to refresh it) with this query (seen in debug messages): `...Execute Statement: select "ORDER_ID","TABLE_ID","TAKEN_BY","ORDER_STATUS_ID","TOTAL_COST"
from(SELECT P.ORDER_ID,
       P.TABLE_ID,
       P.TAKEN_BY,
       P.ORDER_STATUS_ID,
       P.TOTAL_COST
FROM ORDER_DETAILS P
WHERE P.ORDER_STATUS_ID=1
)q
where "ORDER_ID"=:apex$1`

Answer (score -1):

When i tried do alter the process from the "Interactive Grid - Automatic Row Processing (DML)" that apex creats, for my own custom  PL/SQL Code i needed to choose one of the columns from the query to be the primary key, and then i could use the pl/sql custom process as found here on this blog:
https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2019/07/23/customizing-dml-in-an-apex-interactive-grid/ without the no data found error.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.